# matchmaking function when button is submitted

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am making a matchmaking system. I have a button submit that already inserts entries of players to my matching table, but the thing is whenever I'm inserting it, it goes like this (Please see pic 1), My target is to make a matching where players who have the same level gets to match.

> For example Handler1 = level 1 and Handler3 = level 1, they'll be matched because they have the same level.

How can I make this work? Thank you in advance.

[image: This is my target matchmaking system]

Views:

```
 <form autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo base_url('controller/create'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
          <div class="card-body table-responsive py-3 px-3">
            <table id="table_list" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>HandlerID </th>
                  <th>Handler </th>
                  <th>Level </th>
        
        
        
        
        
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
        
        
                <?php foreach ($j->result() as $row) { ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="handlerID[]" value="<?php echo $row->handlerID; ?>"> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="handler[]"   value="<?php echo $row->handler; ?>">   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="level[]"     value="<?php echo $row->level; ?>">     </td>
        
        
        
                  </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        
        
        
          </div>
        
        
        
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function create()
{


$handlerID = $this->input->post('handlerID');
$handler = $this->input->post('handler');
$level = $this->input->post('level');



$data = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($handlerID);$i++) { $data[$i]=array ('handlerID'=> $handlerID[$i], 'handler' => $handler[$i], 'level' => $level[$i]);

  }

  $this->model->createSomething($data);
```

Model:

```
 public function createSomething($data)
  {

  $q = $this->db->insert_batch('matching',$data);
  if ($q)
  {
  return TRUE;
  }
  else return FALSE;

  }
```

Comment: So a level 5 player can't play anyone?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. If there's a player with level 5, and there's no other player with level 5, then "NM" << Means no match 

I do only target for the same level to get in the match. Thank you